# Java build strings based on index value

Tags: java, string, list, stringbuilder

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to assemble a Windows file path in the correct order, given it's directories, here's an example:

```
File: 49ACA1~1.JPG

9 Users
8 user
7 AppData
6 Local
5 MICROS~1
5 Microsoft
4 Windows
3 TEMPOR~1
3 Temporary Internet Files
2 Low
1 Content.IE5
0 MESTLGE4
```

I've already ordered the list by using a custom comparator, based on the input that this function is given, so the highest number is the first directory in the path, and the lowest is the last.

However, as you can see, the numbers 5 and 3 appear twice, this is because they are the same directory, simply referred to by both their 8.3 and full NTFS names.

I'm a bit stumped as to the best way of building a string from these, as whilst they are ordered, once directory 5 is hit, two strings will be needed, one containing the 8.3 names, and the other containing the full ntfs, and I can't tell where the split will happen ahead of time.

This is just a single example, and some files have one directory, whilst others might contain any number, possibly > 20, so I'm hoping to construct this in such a way that it wont be a nightmare to maintain.

I've tried using a `StringBuilder`, but the looping and inserting quickly becomes confusing.  I'm just wondering if there is another, possibly cleaner way of doing this.  I did think about using an `ArrayList`, but I thought that might give the same looping headaches.

I'd be glad for any input or advice.

Thanks

Here's what the output should look like:

```
8.3 = Users\user\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\Windows\TEMPOR~1\Low\Content.IE5\MESTLGE4
NTFS = Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5\MESTLGE4
```

Comment: If you need two **separate** path strings then build `8.3` with the condition for the same order to pick the one that includes `"~"` and the opposite way for `NTFS`.

Comment: I agree with PM 77-1 and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks PM 77-1, that's what I did in the end.  I think I was trying to  over engineer the problem in the end a simple string search did the job.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which type of path you receive (8.3 or full, or combination of both) and just want a working path you can just create a `TreeSet` with your custom comparator and this will take care of the duplicates and ordering.

Comment: Have a look at the desired output OP has posted,